# Accessing id field from paypal stdClass object

Tags: php, paypal, stdclass

I am getting stdClass object from paypal..... when I `var_dump` my data I get the following result....

```
object(stdClass)[264]
public 'id' => string 'PAY-0LC02846YY7884935LBJEJGA' (length=28)
public 'intent' => string 'sale' (length=4)
```

When I access id using `$data->id` it throws error `Undefined property: stdClass::$id` . How to access `id` field